# Riches vs richness

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Is this sentence wrong, and why?

> My richness is having friends.

A friend of mine corrected me in:

> My riches are having friends.

A bit of context. I wanted to say that my friends are my richness (in life), i.e., **my richness (in life) is having friends who care for me** [blah blah blah]

Is this sentence wrong? Did I misuse the word "richness"?

A similar sentence is "My richness is having time to do other things" that I found in this article: https://dairystar.com/Content/News/Print-edition-click-here-/Article/One-breed-farm/1/1/7878.

Comment: It might help if you fully explain the concept you're trying to convey in the sentence. Is this a property of your self or something you own?

Comment: @stef.Your question is confusing.The question is wrong grammatically And semantically.It is not clear what you and your friend want to say or want  it corrected

Comment: @jvl Sorry, I don't understand how "is this sentence wrong?" can be grammatically wrong.

Comment: I suspect that "richness" is more used of rich food (creamy/fatty food), and "wealth" or "riches" would be used for something valuable. Also "My riches are having friends" is ambiguous: people might take it as "are having" (present continuous verb) rather than "are" + "having friends".

Comment: Having can not  be used in the sense of possession.

Comment: @KillingTime It's like in this sentence "My richness is having time to do other things" he said. Taken from https://dairystar.com/Content/News/Print-edition-click-here-/Article/One-breed-farm/1/1/7878.
I wanted to say that my richness is having a lot of friends who care for me etc. etc.

Comment: @jvl So, having time or having friends is not correct?

Comment: I am having a  good time is correct. I am having  friends is wrong

Comment: @jvl: I disagree. https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/have

Comment: @Stef. After the edit your question is correct.

Comment: @Stef. After the edit your question is correct.

Comment: @stef.i have up voted your question and edited my answer. please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Both mean slightly different things but are grammatically correct.

> My richness is having friends.

This means the thing that gives you depth as a person is your contacts.  Richness comes from within.  A chocolate cake's richness is its flavor.  A hermit's richness is sage advice.

> My riches are having friends.

This means the thing you treasure is having friends.  A mother's riches could be her children, while Scrooge McDuck's riches were his literal piles of money.

Answer (score 0):

> My richness is having friends

I actually think that it's ok to say this, and people should understand what you mean. It doesn't seem quite right to me as a native BrE speaker though.

Richness is a level of 'wealth' (be it monetary or spiritual or of life).

Saying your richness is having friends implies that is the only cause of your riches and you have nothing else of value. (unless that is exactly what you mean)

If you feel richer (in life) because you have good friends, the phrase I would use is

> I am richer for having good friends.

Based on comments:

> My most valuable riches are my friends

Comment: Thanks, what I was trying to convey is that friends (who care about me, etc) are the most valuable thing I have in life.

Answer (score 0):

Your original sentence conveys the idea you intend if the context is known. Without context, it can be hard to deduce what you intended.

The following definition conveys something of what your sentence hints at:

> **richness** *noun*
>   1 The state of existing in or containing plentiful quantities of something desirable.
>   ‘tropical gardens with an enormous richness of flora and fauna’
>   [- lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/richness)

However, hearers are more likely to default to a figurative version of definition 1.1 (richness of sauce due to fats and sugars) or a metaphysical version of definition 2 (richness of voice or colour) because these come up more commonly in speech than richness of being.

You’re trying to say that your wealth consists of having friends, not that having friends makes you sweeter. This makes your version somewhat awkward.

Your friend’s version doesn’t work because using plural agreement with “riches” in that way makes the “friends” friends of the riches, rather than *your* friends. It might work, after a fashion, if you were talking about earning interest on a term deposit: the money (riches) you deposited has garnered a few friends (interest earned). But this is a far cry from what you’re trying to convey.

Comment: Richness is never an adjective

Comment: @JVL My mistake. Corrected.